# Maximal tetrahedra inscribed in ellipsoid

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, calculus-of-variations

Pietro Majer quoted the theorem of Michel Chasles in his MO question,
"[Convex curves with many inscribed triangles maximizing perimeter](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78165/),"
which states that the triangles of maximum perimeter inscribed in an ellipse form a one-parameter family, all "billiard triangles."
(This theorem is a special case of Theorem 17.6.6 in Berger's

[Geometry II](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/geometry/book/978-3-540-17015-0),
p.243, which establishes the result for convex $n$-gons.)
My question is whether or not any generalization to higher dimensions is known, and in particular,
whether there is an analogous theorem for tetrahedra inscribed in ellipsoids in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Presumably the generalization would state that there is a two-parameter family of
maximum surface-area tetrahedra inscribed in an ellipsoid.
I have not found such a theorem, and would be interested to learn whether or not it (or
some variant) is known.

                 
[image: Ellipsoid]

**Update**. Here is Henry Cohn's example, just showing the $z=0$ ellipse slice
that contains his degenerate maximal tetrahedra:

                 
[image: Cohn]

Comment: Something maybe related: Oded Schramm's "How to Cage an Egg" proves that there is a 6 dimensional family of convex tetrahedra which "midscribe" an ellipsoid (that is, all its edges are _tangent_ to the ellipsoid). http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002109468

Comment: @jc: Very cool!  I didn't know about this theorem.  It appears to be connected to "Thurston's proof that the sphere can be midscribed by a polytope of given combinatorics."

Comment: I'm not surprised that ellipses don't have this property; it's good to have Henry's counterexample. Two comments: First, for the sphere (a special case), there is a *three*-parameter family of maximal surface-area tetrahedra inscribed in the sphere, namely the regular ones. Thus, the first question would seem to be "Are there any other convex bodies besides the sphere that support a $3$-parameter family?". Second, an analysis similar to the one for ellipses in the plane indicates that there may well be many other surfaces that support a $2$-parameter family. Details follow when time permits.

Comment: @Robert: Nice question re sphere & 3-parameter family!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't proved anything, just done some numerical experiments, but I do not think there is always a two-parameter family of maximum-surface-area tetrahedra incribed in an ellipsoid (although you do get a two-parameter family of regular tetrahedra inscribed in a sphere).  For the ellipsoid defined by $x^2+2y^2+3z^2=1$, the maximum surface area appears to be $2\sqrt{2}$, and it is achieved by the one-parameter family of degenerate tetrahedra with vertices $\pm (\alpha,\sqrt{(1-\alpha^2)/2},0)$ and $\pm (-\sqrt{1-\alpha^2},\alpha/\sqrt{2},0)$ for $-1 \le \alpha \le 1$.  These are the only maximum-surface-area tetrahedra my program found for this ellipsoid.

Comment: Very nice!! Although this shows the generalization I suggested does not hold, it may be that you have uncovered a different theorem here.
These degenerate tetrahedra are the maximum-area quadrilaterals inscribed in the "fattest" slice of the ellipsoid.