# Visualizing results of Gay-Berne model?

Tags: mathematical-software

After I have done with some Monte Carlo simulation of Gay-Berne model, I want to visualize how the N molecules look like in the domain. Here the N molecules all have the same ellipsoidal shape. The centre positions $\mathbf{r}_i$ and the orientations $\mathbf{u}_i$ are given. Is there any software that can plot the configuration of these N molecules based on the given information? Either 3D or 2D is fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost any mathematical package will suffice: Matlab, Mathematica, Sage, ...
Here is an image made in Mathematica, with the ellipses drawn by the `Circle[]` function,
and then oriented with `Rotate[]`:

          [image: ellipses]
One can also draw 3D ellipsoids in these packages.  See the earlier MO question,
"[Maximual tetrahedra inscribed in an ellipsoid](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78572/)" for an example (using `Rotate[Scale[Sphere[]]]`).

Comment: I found that pdeellip() in Matlab has similar functionality. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes. Here is the man page on that Matlab function, in case anyone wants to use it: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/pde/ug/pdeellip.html

Comment: For N=1089 particles, calling pdeellip() makes Matlab run out of memory. Strange. I'll try Mathematica and see if it's better.

Comment: $10^3$ particles should be no challenge; $10^6$ might be a challenge.  I don't use Matlab as regularly as Mathematica, so I cannot help you.  But you could post a question on a Matlab forum, and get quick expert advice.

Comment: I found Mathematica can handle $10^3$ particles quite easily, and produce nice graphs. I'll just use Mathematica. Thanks a lot! 